# Swift NSURLConnection deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to do a URL request to an api and return the results.

I am using NSURLConnection in Swift 2

```
let requestString = "URL HERE"
let urlPath: String = requestString
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
        connection.start()
```

but I keep getting this warning:

```
'init(request:delegate:startImmediately:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use NSURLSession (see NSURLSession.h)
```

I googled the warning and came up with nothing....how do I fix this?

Comment: Use NSURLSession (see NSURLSession.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what the message tells you to do!  Use NSURLSession instead. It replaces NSURLConnection, and is far better.